# Microsoft Confidential at the bottom of list

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, microsoft

This recently started showing up on the bottom of some of our lists, my searches haven't found anything to indicate why this would have started happening.

[image]

Strangely some users have lost the ability to edit in the datagrid now.

Comment: Not completely sure, but might be something updated from Microsoft side as other SharePoint users also seeing the same. check this: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/ami-diamond-70a798b_does-anyone-know-why-in-the-search-result-activity-6762727754438844416-8hG-

Comment: Also, this: https://twitter.com/fowl2/status/1356485584735244288

Comment: Just reproduced this behavior on all sites and multiple environments. Clearly there is something going on with Microsoft side. But I don’t have problems with data grid though. Maybe you should take a look at other locations and see if you have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have users experiencing this, but cannot replicate it myself - likely because I am the SharePoint Admin.
Just checked the O365 Admin Console and saw this:

[image]

This is an issue on Microsoft's End - they are likely backing out whatever update caused this issue.  If you have access to the O365 Admin Center, you can ***subscribe to any updates to this advisory*** as well as ***report that your tenant is experiencing the issue***.

If you have access to the O365 Admin Center, [here](https://admin.microsoft.com/?source=applauncher#/servicehealth/advisories/:/alerts/SP237746) is the direct link to the advisory.

Comment: Please Up Vote if this 'Answer' helped you!

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved by MicroSoft as per their post to the admin center’s message center.
[image: MSFT DECLARED THE ISSUE RESOLVED]